# In Groovy - Entire list version treating as a single string. how to list it as a single single version?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am performing below task in jenkinsfile using groovy. where i have below variables

```
stage('version') {
        steps { script {
            def tagversion = sh(script:''' git tag --sort=v:refname ''', returnStdout:true).trim().readLines().join(',\n')
            echo tagversion
        }}
    }
B='1.12'
for (i = 0; i < tagversion.size(); i++) {
       if (tagversion[i] == B) {
          println "start deploying tagversion one by one"
       }
```

The output of above command is,

```
tagversion 1.0,
1.6,
1.7.1,
1.8,
1.9,
1.10.0,
1.11.0,
1.12


start deploying tagversion one by one
```

when i am trying to iterate this in for loop its treating this tagversion as a single string rather than single-single version.

Expected output-

```
it should iterate one by one and compare till its equals to matched version. 
example-
tagversion[i] == B

1.6 == 1.12
start deploying 1.6 one by one
1.7.1 == 1.12
start deploying 1.7.1 one by one
1.8 == 1.12
start deploying 1.8 one by one
1.9 == 1.12
start deploying 1.9 one by one
1.10.0 == 1.12
start deploying 1.10.0 one by one
1.11.0 == 1.12
start deploying 1.11.0 one by one
1.12 == 1.12
Matched !! no deployment required....
```

am i using the correct way to iterate the version in for loop  on the basis of size?
for (i = 0; i < **tagversion.size()**; i++)

Comment: remove `join` from your code

Comment: if i remove join then it also its treating this as a entire string

Comment: ok. where the `for-loop` code located relatively to step with `sh` and how you are passing the `tagversion` value between those 2 points?

Comment: @daggett - this issue i resolved it. can you check on this issue and suggest please- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755100/in-groovy-how-to-iterate-the-version-list-at-the-exact-index-position-and-compa