# In Groovy -How to iterate the version list at the exact index position and compare it in for loop?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get the matched version of B='1.7' and start iteration and deploying the version till it match to version A='1.12' but it's not doing as expected.

```
​def C = ['1.0', '1.6', '1.7', '1.7.1', '1.10.0', '1.11.0', '1.12']
A='1.12'
B='1.7'

     for(item in C){
       //println item
       if (B >= item && A <= item) {         
          println "deploy the version ${item}"
       }
   } 
​
```

**Output-**

```
deploy the version 1.7
deploy the version 1.12
```

**Expected output**

```
deploy the version 1.7
deploy the version 1.7.1
deploy the version 1.10.0
deploy the version 1.11.0
deploy the version 1.12
```

Please help me what I am doing wrong and just want to know is this a correct way of version comparison?

Comment: I *think* you mean you want to find the indexes of two different values and iterate over just that range? Which also answers the question, if that’s what the non-sensical code snippet means.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Added expected output.

Comment: I believe what I commented implies what you need to do; what further information is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your input list may not always be sorted. In that case:

```
def c = ['1.10.1', '1.0', '1.6', '1.7', '1.7.1', '1.10.0', '1.11.0', '1.12']
def high='1.12'
def low='1.7'

def compareVals = { leftVal, rightVal ->
    [leftVal, rightVal]*.tokenize('.')
        .with { a, b -> [a, b].transpose() 
        .findResult { x, y -> (x.toInteger() <=> y.toInteger()) ?: null}
         ?: a.size() <=> b.size()
    }
}

c.sort{s1, s2 -> compareVals(s1,s2)}
 .subList(c.indexOf(low), c.indexOf(high)+1)
 .each {println "Deploy Version ${it}"}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Deploy Version 1.7
Deploy Version 1.7.1
Deploy Version 1.10.0
Deploy Version 1.10.1
Deploy Version 1.11.0
Deploy Version 1.12
```